# Compiler not interpreting well pointers to string literals as arguments for a method

Tags: c++, string, pointers, methods, arguments

noob here. Having a doubt while doing an exercise from a book.

The doubt is the following: Why if I use a *const std::string ** as an argument to a method, the compiler sends me the following error: *no matching function for call to 'BankAccount::define(const char [11], const char [11], int)'* in the client?

If I swap the prototype and definition of the method to accept as an argument a *const std::string &* (like I did in the constructor) it's no problem for the compiler.

Client:

```
// usebacnt.cpp --

#include "BankAccount.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    BankAccount john;
    BankAccount mary("Mary Wilkinson", "5000000000"); // balance set to 0 because of default argument
    john.display();
    mary.display();
    john.define("John Smith", "4000000000", 26); // error line
    mary.deposit(1000.50);
    john.withdraw(25);
    john.display();
    mary.display();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Class declaration:

```
// BankAccount.h -- Header file for project Exercise 10.1

#ifndef BANKACCOUNT_H_
#define BANKACCOUNT_H_

#include <string>

class BankAccount
{
private:
    std::string fullName;
    std::string accountNumber;
    double balance;
public:
    BankAccount(); // default constructor
    BankAccount(const std::string &fN, const std::string &aN, double b = 0.0); // constructor with a default argument
    void display() const;
    void deposit(double amount);
    void withdraw(double amount);
    void define(const std::string *pfN, const std::string *paN, double b);
};

#endif
```

Class implementation:

```
// methods.cpp -- Compile alongside usebacnt.cpp

#include "BankAccount.h"
#include <iostream>

void BankAccount::display() const
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::ios_base;
    ios_base::fmtflags orig = cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield); // formatting output and saving original
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << "Full Name: " << fullName << '\n';
    cout << "Account Number: " << accountNumber << '\n';
    cout << "Balance: " << balance << "\n\n";
    cout.setf(orig);
}

void BankAccount::deposit(double amount)
{
    if (amount < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "You can't deposit a negative number! Amount set to zero.";
        amount = 0;
    }
    balance += amount;
}

void BankAccount::withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (amount < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "You can't withdraw a negative number! Amount set to zero.";
        amount = 0;
    }
    if (balance < amount)
    {
        std::cout << "You can't withdraw more money than you have. Amount set to zero.";
        amount = 0;
    }
    balance -= amount;
}

void BankAccount::define(const std::string *pfN, const std::string *paN, double b)
{
    fullName = *fN;
    accountNumber = *aN;
    balance = b;
}

// constructors
BankAccount::BankAccount() // default constructor
{
    fullName = "empty";
    accountNumber = "empty";
    balance = 0.0;
}

BankAccount::BankAccount(const std::string &fN, const std::string &aN, double b) // constructor with default argument
{
    fullName = fN;
    accountNumber = aN;
    balance = b;
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler interpret the literal as a string object (like it does with the reference)? So if I say it's a pointer it should pass the address of the string (its first element).

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the compiler interpret the literal as a string object (like it does with the reference)?

No. Pointers are not references; smack anyone who tells you that they are.

It all comes down to this: `std::string` is not a string literal. Therefore, when you pass a string literal to a function that takes a `std::string`, a temporary `std::string` that holds the contents of the literal must be created. This is done with the conversion constructor of `std::string`.

A `const&` is allowed to be initialized from a temporary, which allows conversion constructors to work their magic. A `const*` must be a pointer, and you're not supposed to get pointers to temporaries. Therefore, `const*` cannot be magically filled in by a temporary created from a conversion constructor.

You should use a `const std::string &` instead of a pointer. Or a `std::string` value if you have C++11 move constructors available.

Comment: So, following your logic: 1. if it's a reference. the compiler creates a temporary object to hold the string and passes a reference to it to the method. the method works with it and when it's finished the temporary object expires. 2. if it's a pointer to a string object, the compiler can't create a temporary object and assign the pointer the address of its first element. Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: @Kurospidey: The reason for this is that pointers and references are *different*. They're not intended to be interchangeable. The *technical* reason is that pointers are a C construct and thus have to obey the rules of C constructs. References were new to C++, and thus they could give them properties that didn't exist in C.

Comment: thanks for your help. So "conversion constructors" (i don't know yet what that kind of constructor is) can't read the literal and create the temporary object, and then the client assigns the address of its first element to the pointer. but they can create a temporary object and then the client creates a reference to it. My guess is that constructors do the whole proccess, it's not like the client creates the reference or the pointer on their own. It's a weird concept to assimilate from a noob to which c++ is his first language.

Comment: @Kurospidey: It's a fine concept; the problem is that you keep trying to equate pointers and references. They are not the same thing; there are operations that references can do that pointers can't. By design. And if you're new to C++, you should be *avoiding* pointers.

Comment: (I can't use the @ and don't know why). Tried a workaround (just testing btw). created a couple of string objects, test1 and test2, inside of main and initialized them. Then used them as arguments like this: john.define(&test1, &test2, 26). And it worked. Obviously you were right, in this second case I'm passing the addresses. While in the first case i was passing the objects and the compiler was looking for the addresses (&"Hello" didn't work either).

Comment: @Kurospidey: the @ won't work for Nicol here, as he will be notified anyway as he is the owner of the answer. Regarding your learning process, I find that many people confuse the *concept* with the *implementation*, and that leads to further confusion. The *concept* of a reference is an *alias* to another object, and you can have an *alias* to a temporary. The *implementation* might be a pointer (or not, depending on the context), but you should not care about it at all. For most cases, that is an implementation detail you should not care about.

Comment: and btw, the confusion came from c style strings. I'm pretty sure if I pass a c style string literal as an argument to a regular function that expects a pointer, it takes the address of its first element and the compiler doesn't give me any error. Just thinking and thinking about this xDD

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas thanks for your answer. my main problem was the one I put before. I began with c style strings, maybe I'm wrong and my memory fails (correct me please if I am) but, what i said before: wouldn't the compiler pass to a regular function with a string literal, a pointer to its first element (if the function expected a pointer to a char) automatically? Also when you define a char * and assign a string literal to it the compiler gives it the address of its first element.

Comment: @Kurospidey: Yes, arrays decay to pointers to the first element, and literals are arrays of const characters. But don't get confused, if you were to use string literal, given a literal "Hi" (type `const char [3]`), a function that takes that literal would be a `const char*`, not a `const char (*)[3]` --this might be more confusing but the important point is that it will not be a pointer to the literal, but a pointer to the first character of the literal. Even if literals where `std::string`, you would not be able to pass a literal to a function requiring a pointer, (or `&"Hi"` if allowed)